# Calculate age via JS (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this code to get data from back -end

```
 $('#display').click(function () {
    var vacancyId = $("#vacancy").val();
    var model = {
        vacancyId: vacancyId
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Links", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var question2 = data;
            for (var i = 0; i <= question2.length - 1; i++) {
                var videoHTML = '<div style="width:100%;overflow-y: scroll;background:white;height:72%">' + '<div style="float:left; width:50%;height:296px;border-style:solid;margin-bottom:10px;">' +
                    '<video  style="width:100%;height:290px; object-fit: contain;" controls>';
                videoHTML += '<source src="' + document.location.origin + "/uploads/" + question2[i].Linkes + ".webm" + '" type="video/webm">';
                videoHTML += '</video>' + '</div>' + '<div style="float:right;width:48%;text-align:center;height:296px;border-style:solid;padding-top:30px;">' + '<div>' + '<b>' + "Ф.И.О:  " + '</b>' + '<b>' + question2[i].FIO + '</b>' + '</div>' + '<div>' + '<b>' + "Город:  " + '</b>' + '<b>' + question2[i].City + '</b>' + '</div>' + '<div>' + '<b>' + "Город:  " + '</b>' + '<b>' + question2[i].Vozrast + '</b>' + '</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>';
                $(".videolist").append(videoHTML);

            }
        }
    });
});
```

This one return date of birthday `'<b>' + question2[i].Vozrast + '</b>'`

I need to display age.

How I can do this on client-side?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in server side or client side depend on you.
If you like to do it in client side and Vozrast type is Date, so you can use third libraries to do this e.g. Moment.Js

```
var years = moment().diff(Vozrast, 'years');
var days = moment().diff(Vozrast, 'days');
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this on client side

`var today = new Date();
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();`

Get year like this

And get age like this

```
(yyyy - question2[i].Vozrast)
```